# Django Rest Framework Many=False producing errors

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am stuck on trying to solve an issue with the Serializers and related fields using the django-rest-framework.  Currently I have a model that looks like this:

```
class DataSetModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

class DataPointModel(models.Model):
    dataSet = models.ForeignKey(DataSetModel, related_name='dataPoints')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My serializers look like this:

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataPointModel
        fields = ('pk','label')

class DataSetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dataPoints = DataPointSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DataSetModel
        fields = ('pk','title')
```

The problem I am having is when I try to change the "many=False" in the serializer produces this error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `label` on
>   serializer `DataPointSerializer`.  The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager`
>   instance.  Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no
>   attribute 'label'.

Since this is only ever one model object (one-to-many relationship), I want to get the result as a single object vs a list of one object.

Am I doing this the right way?  I thought that turning the "many=False" it would fetch the first record in an nested query.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `many=False`, because `dataPoints` is a related field that returns a queryset containing a list of instances, not just an instance.

When you do `DataPointModel.dataPoints` that returns a queryset, it can't returns just an instance.  So setting `many=False`, it wouldn't get the first element of the list.

Comment: Levi, thanks for the answer.  How would you suggest handling this in my Model set-up?

Comment: @renderbox why is your point? what do you want to do ? render just one instance model ?

Comment: I am nesting the serialized model so it's just one call to the server.  The point is to not have to go through extra processing on the client end (of processing a list) and having it be delivered ready to be consumed.

Answer (score 1):

So the solve I came to was refactoring my models with where the Foreign Keys are attached.

Here is the fix I implemented:

```
class DataSetModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    dataPoint = models.ForeignKey(DataPointModel)

class DataPointModel(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Moving it to the DataSetModel automatically joins the data model if you set 'many=False' in the Serializer object.

Answer (score 1):

Write your DataPointModel as below. It should work then

```
class DataPointModel(models.Model):
    dataSet = models.OneToOneField(DataSetModel, related_name='dataPoints')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```